# Simple ellipsis function in jQuery to return 2 values

Tags: jquery, function, truncate, ellipsis

So basically I'm trying to get the initial value of the text before being truncated and stuffing it into the rel attribute, while leaving the truncated text truncated.

I can't seem to figure out how to get the function to return the value of the text before truncating it!

Any ideas?

http://jsfiddle.net/TF6Rb/625/

Comment: Fiddles are good, but it's best to include the relevant code in the question itself - thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just grab the text and stuff it into the `rel` before you do anything with it?

```
var text = el.html();
el.attr('rel', text);
// etc
```